# Trying to start firefox from a batch file (task scheduler), but it starts internet explorer instead

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to start firefox from a batch file via the windows 7 task scheduler, but it's starting internet explorer instead.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

batch file code:

```
start /B "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox 4.0 Beta 8\firefox.exe" http://somewebsite.com
ping 127.1.1.
start /B "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox 4.0 Beta 8\firefox.exe" http://www.google.com
```

Answer (score 1):

The start command uses the `first double quoted term` as a `window title`, so it was not launching firefox, but was launching the `default browser` by association.

The changes below are the `""` in each start command, and then it will launch the program as shown in the command.

The ping command also has an enhancement and will pause for about 10 seconds.

```
start /B "" "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox 4.0 Beta 8\firefox.exe" http://somewebsite.com

ping -n 10 localhost >nul

start /B "" "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox 4.0 Beta 8\firefox.exe" http://www.google.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the path exists first and remove start /B

just use  the   path_to_exe arg1

Answer (score 0):

Make it default browser was the trick.

Answer (score 0):

run this command:

```
@start iexplore "http://www.cnn.com"
```